# Automapper and SimpleInjector using WebApiRequestLifestyle

Tags: automapper, simple-injector, automapper-4

I'm inserting Automapper (latest version from Nuget) into my project (WebApi2, framework 4.5.1) and using SimpleInjector (latest version from Nuget).

My problem is that before using Automapper everything worked. Now I'm not sure why it is telling me that a reverse mapping is missing (when I know it's not needed for the service being called).

I'm using the IMappingEngine interface.

I have a AutoMapperConfig class with all the Mapper.CreateMap

**Example of AutoMapperConfig**

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig 
{
    public static void Configure(IMappingEngine mappingEngine)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, EntityModel>()
        ...
    }
}
```

The reason AutoMapperConfig.Configure is receiving an IMappingEngine is that some mappings attributs have other mapping inside. For example (snippet of code):
**(Note the Mapper.Map inside the Mapper.CreateMap)**

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Req, ReqModel>()
    .ForMember(
        opt => opt.MapFrom(
            src => new ServiceModel(mappingEngine)
            {
                Id = src.Plan.Id,
                Name = src.Plan.Service.Name,
                ServiceTypeId = src.Plan.Service.Type.Id,
                Type = Mapper.Map<TypeModel>(src.Plan.Service.Type)
            }))
```

In **Global.asax** (method Application_Start()) I'm calling:

```
AutoMapperConfig.Configure(Mapper.Engine);
```

In **SimpleInjector** registrations I'm using:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<IMappingEngine>(Mapper.Engine);
AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration.ConstructServicesUsing(container.GetInstance);
```

Then each **Controller** receives a IMappingEngine and uses:

```
MappingEngine.Map
```

Anything missing or wrong?

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.